# Front-page not displaying questions

Tags: support, bug

I always go to mathoverflow.net rather than mathoverflow.net/questions, because the latter only shows 50 results per page including results in tabs you've hidden (so I only see about 4 per page). Normally  the  former  option  displays   loads  of  questions ( always a  superset  of  those  in  the  question  tab). However, it seems the former is no longer displaying questions at all. Have others noticed this too? Is this by design?

Comment: I just asked a similar question on the MSE meta http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/11576/hiding-ignored-tags-hides-all-questions.

Comment: (I do not have the problem on MO, as I don't have the any ignored tags here, nor the "hide ignored tags" enabled).

Comment: I just tried replicating the bug here on MO by adding a few ignored tags (that I knew had questions on the active page) and enabling "hide ignored tags", but it worked as intended here. It may only happen if you have enough ignored tags.

Comment: I'd recommend to retag this as [meta-tag:bug], that way the SE developers will see it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This was unexpected fallout from a change that was intended to limit the impact of requests with an excessively large list of tag criteria. The issue related to a very large number of ignored tags (331) with the "hide ignored tags" preference enabled. I have revised the limits while I investigate further. Sorry for any disruption.

Comment: Thanks. It seems fixed.